# Xamarin form: Use MediaPlugin to take photo. Image was not show as what was taken after crop

Tags: ios, image, xamarin, orientation

I am using the MediaPlugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin. Normally, if I not set the allowCropping to true, the image showing in the Image view does show what it was taken. But if it was set, the cropped image not showing the same orientation as it was taken.

The image I was taken was in Portrait. After cropped, the image was rotated in the image view.

Comment: Image rotation with this plugin is not reliable (I think). Look at this bug: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/285. It's closed but people still having issues. I suggest you to rotate images by yourself (by reading image's EXIF information) or make camera renderers by yourself... or try to find another plugin (if you find, make us sign)